# Testing the text in an ionic app's view with karma/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, ionic-framework, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm writing an ionic app with karma/jasmine testing frameworks.

I'm trying to figure out how to test that the text in my view is as inteded because last week i pushed code to google play with the wrong text.

I currently have:

```
<div id="someid">
    this is some text that i want to test
</div>
```

Inside of my:

```
 <ion-view></ion-view>
```

How can i retreive that into my test to test my text?

Will using angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find() be an error-free solution, or do i need to create a directive?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be best to create a directive that produces that text in its template, then test the directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-directives

Comment: Your question shuld be more concrete. Please, improve it, or it will be deleted as too broad. So what yu have tried, or explain exactly what you want to do. As it's stated a simple answer is "extract the text with jQuery $('#someid').text() and compare it with what you want". So the problem must be more concrete or complex.

Comment: What about now? I narrowed it down.